# Decompressing with PyLZMA

Tags: python, compression, zip, lzma

I compress my files using this script

```
import pylzma, struct
i = open(path+fileName,'rb')
o = open(path+zipName+'.zip','wb')
data = i.read()
c = pylzma.compressfile(data, eos=1)
result = c.read(5)
result += struct.pack('<Q', len(data))
o.write(result + c.read())
i.close()
o.close()
```

I use this method as shown in the [PyLZMA documentation](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/3d308de8b559ef5b7b5e1566cbc929d1fe278eda/doc/usage.txt) because it allows my files to be readable by 7zip or lzma.exe. Decompression using 7zip works fine but it does not work when I use PyLZMA. I use this:

```
i = open(path+name+'.zip', 'rb')
o = open(path+name, 'wb')
data = i.read()
u = pylzma.decompress(data)
o.write(u)
```

It stops on pylzma.decompress and I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Error while decompressing: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading the [documentation](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/doc/USAGE.md) correctly (I'm having trouble installing PyLZMA so I am unable to verify), `compress()` outputs a string that `decompress()` can handle.

However, in order to make the compressed string compatible with other utilities, it is necessary to insert the 8-byte length in between the first 5 bytes and the rest of the compressed data.

Thus, if you want to decompress the data using PyLZMA, I suspect you will need to manually remove that 8-byte length field (quickest way would probably be to open the input file, read 5 bytes, skip 8, then read the remainder of the file).

Comment: Interesting, I will check that out. If you didn't figure out how to install PyLZMA, you may try easy_install